# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in Python Nested Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

In the following code, `queryResult` is a Nested Lists. A nested list means all of the list values had another list.

**LIKE:**

```
[(1024, jkhsa97890),(1025, khka65757),(1025, kjhaksd87987), ....]
```

So with the first loop, we are getting lists from`queryResult` and storing them in the record.

**ARRAYS STORED IN RECORD:**

```
(1024, jkhsasa97890)
(1025, khkaada65757)
(1025, kjhaksd87987)
....
```

Then with the second for loop from the lists in `record`, we are getting values, which are then copied to a `dictionary` by providing keys to each value.

But error occurs at `value4['videoid'] = item[0]` . The `value4['videoid']` is dictionary key, and `item[0]` is an integer whose value for the first iteration is 1024.

Similarly, `value4['videokey']` is dictionary key, and `item[1]` is a string and for the first iteration, it is `jkhsasa97890` and so on.

**CODE:**

```
value4 = dict() 

for record in queryResult:

    for item in record:
        value4['videoid'] = item[0]
        value4['videokey'] = item[1]
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\demo.py", line 118, in <module>
    value4['videoid'] = item[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

After each completion of the nested loop, values are stored in another place before they are overridden.

Comment: please tell us the data type for `item`; your nested loop for `record` is fetching one item at a time for the current row

Comment: Try to debug your code to see the value of `item` when it fails, or you can add a `try/except` clause to display the value of `item` when there is an error.

Comment: @anurag, Kindly check question has been re-modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list is a two level nest list. You do not need a nested loop for dispatching your values. In your first loop on queryResult you get in record the tuples. At that point record already contains what you want to get individual element by their indexes.

```
value4 = dict() 
for record in queryResult:          # example : record = (1024, "jkhsasa97890")
    value4['videoid'] = record[0]   # record[0] is 1024
    value4['videokey'] = record[1]  # record[1] is "jkhsasa97890"
```

Comment: the Question is just modified. I hope now it will clear all your queries.

Comment: I just modified my answer to match your update but my code is still valid. You do not need nested loop for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Niko B. First I did not get you.